# Executing stored procedure in Java class

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a stored procedure that I want to execute within a Java class. I have the values of the stored procedure within the SQL of the procedure and want to be able to execute it fully in a Java class.
Below is the stored procedure:

```
exec @sta = storedProcedureName
        @TFT = 'Value',
        @TFTRW = 'Value2',
        @TRTF_Num = 1,
```

Since I already have the full statement I tried to execute it using a prepared statement but got the below error:

```
must declare variable @sta
```

Does anyone know how I can just execute the stored procedure above in my class or do I have to prepare a callable statement and substitute the values in as Strings and Ints?

Comment: Please post your Java code as part of your question so we can help you.

Comment: Use CallableStatement for stored procedures